# Location Listener In Service

Tags: android, service, location

I need a service in my reminder program to check location repeatedly and I'm doing that with this code but I get force close when service started:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    ll = new Mylocationlistener();
    checkPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",1,0);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
    return START_STICKY;
}

private class Mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location changed" + location.getLatitude() + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `Service` for that? You could simply do this job in your `MainActivity` class.

Comment: because i need to check location when application is closed @TasosMoustakas

Comment: Are you sure your GPS is enabled, even when the app is closed ?

Comment: im testing application in avd @TasosMoustakas

Comment: Have you tried debugging your application?

Comment: You have to help us more here. What `checkPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",1,0)` does? what parameters does it take? Is it void? If no, does it return boolean ?

Comment: thanks my problem solved when i test in in avd with android 5.1.1 but in 6.0 i still get forceclose @TasosMoustakas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if GPS is enabled, every time your `Service` is triggered. Try this: 
In `onStartCommand`, add a GPS checker:

```
if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
}
```